# Lazy Collection in Laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel

I am currently facing a performance issue because of a query that selects all the IDs in a table and afterwards performs a pluck function. I thought about using Lazy Collections.

I would like to know if there is a way to come up with something similar to the Lazy Collection feature of Laravel 6 in previous versions (currently using Laravel 5.7).
Is there maybe a library that would allow me to have a similar feature for Laravel 5.7?

This is the code I'm trying to optimize (especially the first line of it, which returns 900000+ records and makes the server's MySql returns an "allowed memory size has been exhausted" exception):
https://pastecode.io/s/v9ko4u20ra

Thank you

Comment: you can try (without any guarantee that it will work) adding `illuminate/collections": "^8.0"` in your composer JSON. It may mean you'll need to migrate all collection code to work with Laravel 8

Comment: You can also put in your question the code you're using, maybe we can help you optimize it. You can also, develop a smaller version of that feature that suits your use case.

Comment: The code I'm trying to optimize is this one:
https://pastecode.io/s/v9ko4u20ra

Especially the first line of this code. It's the first query, with the select, has and pluck, that now ends up returning 900000+ records, and as a result the server's MySQL goes into "allowed memory size has been exhausted"

Comment: If you’re trying to load 900,000+ records, I think you need to rethink your UI and/or approach in general, because that’s crazy. Surely you could use autosuggest or something similar to whittle down the results?

Comment: @Pat I highly suggest at least upgrading to Laravel 6, since Laravel 5 isn't getting security updates anymore. If you use [shift](https://laravelshift.com/), you might want to do it before L9 drops this September, as it will cost you more. And since you say it has the feature you need, it would be worth your time.